# mingw32-g++: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, pthreads, mingw32

I am using Windows 8 with MingW as compiler suit. Have tried installing

```
mingw32-libpthreadgc-dll
mingw32-libpthreadgc-dev
```

Tried executing this

```
λ mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g "C:\MinGW\bin\pthreadGC-3.dll" -c main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

This

```
λ mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -lpthreadGC-3 -c main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

This

```
λ mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -lpthreadGC -c main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

And this

```
λ mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -lpthread -c main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

Getting same error everytime

```
error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
```

My `C:\MinGW\bin` contains `pthreadGC-3.dll`, but don't know how to use it.

Here is the version info of the compiler:

```
λ mingw32-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

Could someone help me enable multithreading? I don't think I need to share the code, because the problem is a generic one, but if some needs to have a look at it, I will edit the question.

**EDIT:** Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

typedef std::function<void(void)> task;

class DispatchQueue {
public:
    DispatchQueue(size_t thread_pool_size) {
        std::cout << "Starting dispatch queue with " << thread_pool_size << " threads." << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; i++) {
            threads_.emplace_back(std::thread([this]{task_executer();}));
        }
    }

    ~DispatchQueue() {
        isStopped_ = true;
        condVar_.notify_all();

        std::cout << "Shutting down dispatch queue with " << threads_.size() << " threads." << std::endl;

        for (std::thread& thread : threads_) {
            thread.join();
        }

        std::cout << "Dispatch queue is shut down...";
    }

    void runAsync(const task& t) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniq_lock(mutLock_);
        taskQueue_.push(t);
        condVar_.notify_all();
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
    std::queue<task> taskQueue_;

    std::mutex mutLock_;
    std::condition_variable condVar_;

    bool isStopped_ = false;
    int activeThreadCounter = 0;

    void task_executer() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniq_lock(mutLock_);

        while(!isStopped_ || taskQueue_.size() > 0) {
            condVar_.wait(uniq_lock, [this]{
                return taskQueue_.size() > 0 && isStopped_;
            });

            if (taskQueue_.size() > 0) {
                std::cout << "Active threads: " << ++activeThreadCounter << std::endl;

                const task t = std::move(taskQueue_.front());
                taskQueue_.pop();

                uniq_lock.unlock();

                t();

                uniq_lock.lock();

                --activeThreadCounter;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Editing question now...